# Show that $((x+iy)(\frac 1 x +\frac i y ))^2$ is always less or equal to -4?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I'm trying to figure out all the different (calculus) ways to solve this one.

Given the point $((x+iy)(\frac 1 x +\frac i  y ))^2$, 
where $x,y>0$ are positive real numbers,

a) show that it lies on the negative axis in the complex plane;

b) show that it is always less or equal to $-4$. (for $x,y>0$ and real) .

So for a), I simplified it, and it simply became $-\left(\frac {x^2 + y^2} {yx} \right)^2$. Since $x,y>0$ and real, the number must be negative and real.

For b) however I'm a bit stuck (maybe the mean value theorem?).  I'm interested in all the ways to solve this one so feel free to be creative.

Comment: Did you mean *modulus or absolute value*? Because there is no order on $\;\Bbb C\;$ (as the one we have in $\;\Bbb R$)\

Comment: Well, modulus isn't going to be negative, either ... :P

Comment: Then the product is a real number...ok.\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding the term of interest reveals

$$\left((x+iy)\left(\frac1x+i\frac1y\right)\right)^2=\left((x+iy)\left(\frac1x+i\frac1y\right)\right)^2=-\left(\frac xy+\frac yx\right)^2$$

which is real and negative for $x>0$ and $y>0$.

---

Next, note that the function $f(t)=t+t^{-1}\ge 2$ for $t>0$ (Take the derivative and set it to $0$ to see that $f$ is a minimum at $t=1$ where $f(1)=2$).

Therefore, since $x/y= (y/x)^{-1}$, it is easy to see that for $x>0$ and $y>0$, we have $f(x/y)\le 2$ and hence

$$\frac xy+\frac yx\ge 2$$

whence we see that

$$-\left(\frac xy+\frac yx\right)^2\le -4$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: One can of course simply use the AM–GM inequality to show $t+1/t>2$. And congratulations on 100K!

Comment: @Chappers Yes; even easier.  And thank you!  Your vote just put me over the top with 100,006.  ;-))

Comment: Mark Viola and @Chappers. Cool! thanks guys, I was just wondering if there are also other (calculus) ways to show this, trying to figure out all the ways to do it. Could the Mean Value theorem be used for example?

Answer (score 1):

you still need to show that

$-(\frac {x^2 + y^2}{xy})^2 < -4\\
|\frac {x^2 + y^2}{xy}| > 2\\
x^2 + y^2 > 2|xy|\\
x^2 - 2|xy| + y^2 > 0\\
(|x| - |y|)^2 > 0$

Which is indeed always true.

I missed the note that $x,y>0$  It makes things a little simpler as the absolute value above becomes necessary.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x+iy)\left(\frac1x+\frac1yi\right)=\left(\frac xy+\frac yx\right)i\implies\left[(x+iy)\left(\frac1x+\frac1yi\right)\right]^2=-\left(\frac xy+\frac yx\right)^2=$$

$$=-\frac{x^2}{y^2}-2-\frac{y^2}{x^2}=-\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{x^2y^2}$$

and that's point (a).

For (b):

$$-\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{x^2y^2}\le-4\iff(x^2+y^2)^2\ge4x^2y^2\iff(x^2-y^2)^2\ge0\;\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

$$-(\frac {x^2 + y^2} {yx}  )^2>-4$$

then

$$(\frac {x^2 + y^2} {yx}  )^2<4$$
$$(\frac {x^2 + y^2} {yx}  )^2<2$$

$$x^2 + y^2<2xy$$
$$x^2 + y^2-2xy<0$$
$$(x-y)^2<0$$

which is absurd.